# why there are six getty processes running on my desktop?

Tags: linux, terminal, console

My desktop system is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux xmachine 3.0.0-13-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 2 13:25:36 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

By running `ps a | grep getty`, I get this output:

```
  900 tty4     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
  906 tty5     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
  915 tty2     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
  917 tty3     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
  923 tty6     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
  1280 tty1     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
  5412 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto getty
```

I think ttyX processes is for input/ouput devices but I am not quite sure. Based on this I am wondering that why there are 6 ttyX processes running? I have only one input devices(keyboard) actually.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: *[What is 'Getty'? I noticed there is 6 occurences of it in my System Monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120012)*

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This shows because one `getty` process is running on each virtual console (VC) between `tty1` and `tty6`. You can access them by changing your active virtual console using <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> respectively if you are currently within X).

For more information on what a TTY is, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con), and for information on virtual consoles, see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console).

Answer (score 6):

A Linux machine (running with SystemV) defines a special file, `/etc/inittab` that declares (but not only) how many *getty processes will run and their corresponding terminals. E.g. this is an excerpt of `inittab` on my Gentoo Linux machine:

```
# TERMINALS
c1:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty --noclear 38400 tty1 linux
c2:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty 38400 tty2 linux
c3:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty 38400 tty3 linux
c4:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty 38400 tty4 linux
# Wanting only four terminals!
#c5:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty 38400 tty5 linux
#c6:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty 38400 tty6 linux
```

What makes `agetty` appear on the first terminal, for example, is the `tty1` argument that is passed to `agetty`. you can limit the number of consoles on which you can type your login by commenting out the corresponding lines in `inittab`, i.e put a hash (#) sign on the beginning of the lines.

On my machine I have reduced it to only 4 consoles on which I can login. It is best to at least have one of these active, just in case something goes wrong with the graphic login manager (if you have one).